# Traduction du mot anglais "sharp" en mathématiques

Tags: traduction, anglais, vocabulaire, mathématiques

En mathématiques, le mot anglais *sharp* est souvent utilisé, e.g. *sharp estimate*, *sharp bound* etc. Le sens de ce mot est en quelque sorte : *la meilleure estimation*, *la meilleure limite*, etc.

Existe-t-il un mot équivalent en français ?

J'ajoute un lien vers [la liste du jargon mathématique](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_jargon) sur Wikipédia dans lequel il y a une explication du mot *sharp*.

Comment: Précise, fine, de bonne qualité?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Il semble que dans la plupart des cas, *sharp* ne correspond pas à une définition mathématique précise. Je pense donc qu'on est libre de l'interpréter librement sans introduire d'ambiguïté.

*Sharp* n'a pas de traduction unique en français. Parmi les différents mots français qui peuvent correspondre : *net*, *precis*, *fin*, *affûté*, *fort*, *vif*, *brusque*, *saillant*, *pointu*, *aigu*, etc.

Dans le cas précis donné en exemple par Wikipédia aucun ne fonctionne, excepté peut-être *rasante*. On peut envisager *sur-approximation qui [adhère](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adh%C3%A9rence_%28math%C3%A9matiques%29) à la courbe* (sous entendu, en un point), le seul problème c'est qu'on peut se demander si c'est du jargon flou ou une vraie définition. Également, *tangente à la courbe*, mais ça a là aussi d'autres implications.

Comment: Merci beaucoup. Vous m'avez rassuré :D

Comment: Par ailleurs, si le sens avait été « optimal », ce même terme aurait été utilisé en anglais. Si *sharp* est utilisé c'est qu'il y a une bonne raison, car qu'il ne signifie pas la même chose. En particulier dans l'exemple donné ce n'est pas évident de dire ce qui est optimisé, ce n'est pas la sur-approximation (fonction majorante) elle-même, il faudrait qu'un ordre précis soit défini sur l'espace des fonctions pour cela.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Il y a un ordre précis sur l'espace des fonctions à valeurs réelles. Je ne vois pas bien ce que tu reproches à *optimal*.

Comment: @Evpok: Il y en a plusieurs et aucun n'est total. J'ai même pas envie de me justifier… Un exemple au hasard, considère la famille x ⟼ (x+a)^2 + 1, a ∈ [-∞, +∞], sans autre précision, laquelle est « optimale » ? Il n'y en a pourtant qu'une qui « adhère à » (*sharp approximant of* avec le sens décrit sur Wikipédia) x ⟼ x.

Comment: @Evpok: Hors parenthèse, je vois mal quelqu'un utiliser *sharp* en anglais là où *optimal* est possible et a un sens bien défini. Ça suffit à justifier ma remarque.

Comment: Je ne suis pas d'accord, surtout au niveau de la différence que tu vois entre *sharp* et *optimal*. Tout au moins dans les contextes qui m'intéressent, *sharp* a une définition précise. Par contre, une inégalité peut être *sharp* tandis que la constante associée sera *optimal* (en général... la constante peut être *sharp* aussi). La raison d'avoir un autre mot est que *optimal* est trop utilisé dans trop de contextes.

Answer (score 5):

En ce qui concerne les contraintes, il me semble qu'on parle de **contrainte optimale**, ainsi que l'anglais le permet également (optimal constraint).

J'éditerai ma réponse plus tard si je trouve une bonne source pour confirmer cette idée.

Comment: Merci beaucoup. Optimal est un bon mot.

Comment: On parle aussi de «meilleure constante» (par ex, la meilleure constante de Sobolev) dans le contexte des estimés.

Answer (score 4):

En français on utilisera le mot **optimal**.

Mais dans de nombreux cas la notion correspondante est déjà inclue dans le concept mathématique. Une **borne supérieure**, par exemple, est optimale par définition, est il n'est pas nécessaire d'ajouter un qualificatif.

Comment: Merci beaucoup. C'est une bonne idée d'utiliser un concept mathématique convenable.