# Les « sharp tactical/open games » aux échecs : vocabulaire référant à cette qualité (sharp) recherchée en français ?

Tags: vocabulaire, anglais, usage, adjectifs, comparaison-de-langues

En ce qui a trait indirectement à la [traduction](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/sharp/611081) du mot anglais [*sharp*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sharp), pas en [mathématiques](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/6353) mais plutôt aux [échecs](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/75/very-aggressive-openings), pour parler des ouvertures ou d'un type de partie... D'après une [réponse](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/145845) sur *ELL*, il pourrait s'agir d'un usage basé sur l'idée de (ma traduction du propos de *James K*) *précision*, d'*impulsion* et d'*attaque* (d'[offensivité](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/offensivit%C3%A9) ?). Mais à défaut de pouvoir personnellement l'expliquer précisément, je me demande par ailleurs si un locuteur francophone aurait spontanément fait appel à un adjectif ou à une locution particulière pour qualifier ce type de partie d'échecs ou d'ouverture dont il est fait mention dans cette question « [*Very Aggressive Openings*](https://chess.stackexchange.com/q/75) » sur *Chess SE* où l'on trouve à propos d'une ouverture qu'elle : « [...] makes for a sharp tactical game » et où l'on se demande « What other openings [...] force these kind of very aggressive, tactical, sharp open games? » (parmi une quizaine d'utlisations du mot *sharp* dans cette Q&A si on ajoute les commentaires en plus des réponses...).

---

Quel est le vocabulaire employé au jeu d'échecs en français pour parler de ces types de parties qu'on pourrait vouloir connaître vu ces paramètres particuliers ; ce serait un terme qu'un(e) joueur(se) d'échecs familier(e) avec le vocabulaire emploierait ou qu'on trouverait en littérature spécialisée dans des contextes qui collent à ceux de la question posée en langue anglaise, soit, à l'évidence (+95), une qualité recherchée ; en plus de *recherchées*, ce pourrait être *avant-gardistes/contemporaines, offensives, complexes, brillantes/géniales* ou simplement les *meilleures* parties etc.

---

Un terme s'impose-t-il et y a-t-il aux échecs un usage en français comparable à celui qu'on pourrait retrouver en langue anglaise avec *sharp* pour décrire ces types de parties ?

Comment: Bien finalement j'avais pas vu qu'il y avait une [question](https://chess.stackexchange.com/q/16175) sur ce terme là directement sur Chess, mais la question reste entière en français, par exemple une réponse réfère au [lexique des echecs](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexique_du_jeu_d%27%C3%A9checs) sur Wikipédia mais la version en français ne semble pas contenir de terme dont la définition se rapprocherait de celle de _sharp_ ds. la version en langue [anglaise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_chess#S). Merci !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En ce qui concerne les [« Ouvertures » (les premières phases d'une partie d'échecs)](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ouverture_(%C3%A9checs)#Constitution_d.27un_r.C3.A9pertoire_d.27ouvertures), *Wikipedia* parle des « jeu[x] positionnel[s] calme[s] » et puis des « jeu[x] vif[s] et tactique[s] ».

Ces derniers adjectifs (vif et tactique) me semblent décrire, en gros,  ce que la notion de « a **sharp** game/position/opening/style of play » veut dire en anglais.
En explorant un peu les 3 ouvertures que *Wikipedia* associe avec les parties vives et tactiques, il y a du vocabulaire qui, d’apres moi, peut être vu comme relevant au mot anglais « sharp ».

Dans [cette discussion de « Le gambit Letton »](http://www.mjae.com/letton1.html), on trouve le mot [« **fougueux** »](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/fougueux) qui, d’après mon interprétation de sa définition, peut dire « audacieux », qui ne capte qu’un peu l’idée figurative de « sharp » cherchée ici, d'accord;

mais on y trouve aussi les notions d’être « épingl[é] l'une ou l'autre de ces "**pointures**" » et « du jeu **aigu** », qui ne sont pas trop loin même du sens littéral de « sharp », d’apres moi.

Pour finir, dans [cette discussion de « La Contre-attaque Traxler »](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contre-attaque_Traxler), *Wikipedia* explique que « Cette variante de la défense des deux cavaliers est très [**tranchante**](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/tranchante) et controversée » et d’après *CNRTL-TLFi*, *tranchante* peut décrire quelque chose qui est assez « sharp » pour couper.

Comme « exemples d’usage » de

> « un jeu **aigu** » et
>     « une ligne de jeu **tranchante** »

dans le contexte d’échecs (le jeu),  il y a le passage suivant ([via la page de résultats d’un ‘Google search’](https://www.google.com/search?lr=lang_fr&tbs=lr%3Alang_1fr&tbm=bks&ei=pK8JWr3JKqaZjwTDnKfQBw&q=%22Les+variantes+sont+assez+fouill%C3%A9es+et+conduisent+%C3%A0+un+jeu+aigu.%22+%22une+ligne+de+jeu+tranchante%22&oq=%22Les+variantes+sont+assez+fouill%C3%A9es+et+conduisent+%C3%A0+un+jeu+aigu.%22+%22une+ligne+de+jeu+tranchante%22&gs_l=psy-ab.12...81370.101557.0.103592.4.4.0.0.0.0.835.1429.0j1j4-1j0j1.3.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..1.0.0....0.iPyPUcThIQ0))  de *Jeu d'échecs et société en France au XVIIIème siècle* (2002) par l’historien et joueur d’échecs, [Maxcellend Coulon](http://tpgbesancon.com/blog/2015/03/23/1970-les-championnats-interligues/):

> Les variantes sont assez fouillées et conduisent à **un jeu aigu**. De
>   nos jours, le nom de Greco reste attaché à **une ligne de jeu
>   tranchante**, dans la partie italienne.

Comment: Merci, c'est vraiment excellent, bien documenté, et avec un exemple pertinent ! Vous parliez d'audace par rapport à « fougueux », ça me fait penser aussi à _périlleux_, pour l'aspect « risky ». Vu qu'on a « tranchant » qui au final est bien proche du sens au propre de _sharp_, je me demande même si on ne pourrait pas dire « à double tranchant » pour montrer que les deux adversaires peuvent s'y « couper ». J'ai trouvé ce sujet vraiment intéressant. J'ai appris à jouer quand j'étais enfant mais je ne me suis jamais intéressé à la théorie, et c'était avant l'emploi des bases de données...

Comment: ... et avant que j'aie l'anglais que j'ai aujourd'hui. De sorte que ça me fait comme un _double-whammy_ lors de la lecture de matériel en anglais. C'est un sujet pour ELU et Chess à mon avis, mais vu votre expérience de la vie en général, diriez-vous que le terme _sharp_ tel qu'on en a discuté, a toujours en anglais été associé à ce dont vous avez parlé aux échecs ? Ou est-ce un truc qui est apparu avec les développements de l'analyse théorique assistée par ordinateur ? Je lis disons Fischer et son livre de ses 60 parties mémorables (1969), est-ce que je dois m'attendre à trouver ce terme ?

Comment: J'ai visionné des « lectures » du Saint-Louis Chess Club sur YT et le terme est omniprésent. C'est complètement hors sujet mais j'étais surpris de voir à quel point on s'appuie sur les parties exsitantes en DB pour dire si tel ou tel coup a déjà été joué ou non, indépendamment de la qualité du coup comme tel. Même en utilisant Lucas Chess, j'ai vu que le « tutor » peut m'afficher les pourcentages de fois qu'on a choisi tel coup plutôt que tel autre dans les parties que j'ai en DB. Ultimement je suis curieux de comparer l'idée de popularité des coups et leur qualité. Par exemple, si j'ai une...

Comment: DB constituée uniquement ou non des parties de grands maîtres comme M. Carlsen et Nakamura et al., est-ce que popularité signifie qualité dans ce contexte. Ou quand une jeune joueuse chinoise joue un coup qui est considéré comme un « novelty », est-ce absolument un coup de qualité ou un coup jamais joué dans les DBs... Que de questions ! Je vais réfléchir à ça. Merci encore !

Comment: Finally, this also made me think of _lean & mean_ in some strange ways. Cheers!

Comment: Your going from “my” *trenchant* to *double-tranchant* is what qualifies as being excellent, imo.  I saw that in *TLFi* but I must have glossed over  the «Qui peut produire deux effets opposés, qui peut se retourner contre son auteur» sense which, imo, is a spot-on/perfect way to interpret what “sharp” means in English re chess. I mistakenly took the notion of “double/deux tranchant” (re chess) to be referring only to strong offensive positions/moves like a “knight fork.” @Galèrefranquiste

Comment: @Galèrefranquiste  You'll encounter [“sharp”](https://books.google.com/books?id=Whm_CAAAQBAJ&pg=PA42-IA24&dq=%22DOuble-edged%22+Bobby+fischer&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj4v_C0u77XAhVM34MKHRBtBy0Q6AEINDAC#v=snippet&q=sharp&f=false) in Bobby's book & [“double-edged”](https://books.google.com/books?id=Whm_CAAAQBAJ&pg=PA42-IA24&dq=%22DOuble-edged%22+Bobby+fischer&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj4v_C0u77XAhVM34MKHRBtBy0Q6AEINDAC#v=snippet&q=%22double-edged%22&f=false), too. I used to play alot, but "sharp" never meant anything beyond describing a player or his/her moves as "clever" or maybe the way s/he dressed!